# Firefox and Chrome doesn't show default "not found" page when using PHP to send header 404

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, firefox

I am using Apache + PHP (under Windows), the PHP code is

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
exit;
?>
```

Firefox and Chrome doesn't show the default "not found" page, but IE shows the correct "HTTP error, 404 message", why?

Comment: Ummm I think you'll find it's IE that's not showing the correct error page **because** it's showing "friendly errors" ... it's a browser setting.

Comment: Do they have a default *Page Not Found* page to begin with? There's a *Server Not Found* page but that's a different error.

Comment: If I access a missing.html, both Firefox and Chrome will show default "not found" page, but if I use PHP to send header 404 status, they will not show a normal "not found" page, only show a empty document, nothing.

Comment: @vsqsf15 - That page does not belong to the browser. It's the server response, which IE hides from the user. You can see it for yourself in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Chrome and Firefox display server response as-is under all circumstances, even when it is an empty document. You only see browser own error messages when there *isn't* a server response to display (DNS failure, time out...). Whether you use a server-side language to generate the response or let the web server do it doesn't make any difference.

Internet Explorer, however, has a bug/feature called [Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294807) where the browser will automatically drop the server response under certain conditions (namely, then the document size falls below a given threshold). The rationale is that small responses are likely to be the web server default pages and the user will enjoy most a standard browser page in his own language.

Comment: Server can work fine, If I access a missing.html, both Firefox and Chrome will show default "not found" page, but if I use PHP to send header 404 status, they will not show a normal "not found" page, only show a empty document, nothing.

Comment: Let me guess... Something [like this](http://httpd.apache.org/missing.html)? Nobody at Mozilla or Google designed that page!

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer, this issue may be caused by Apache, while I access a missing html, it will response, something like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /missing.html was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

but when I use the above PHP script to send a HTTP 404 message, apache will only response a empty document.

BTW, I don't set any ErrorDocument in httpd.conf.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this is the page you're seeing in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header `Content-Type: text/plain` in the response.
I had a similar bug where the header was `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` so the browsears treated it as it was a binary file, not a string message